# Underscore collection pluck returning undefineds

Tags: backbone.js, collections, underscore.js

I'm new to backbone/underscore/jquery and im having a problem with the pluck method. I can log the entire collection and see that i have 20 or so models (correct terminology?) in there all with various attributes.

When i use this piece of code the entire collection is iterated but every model's lat field comes back as undefined so i just end up with 20 undefined. Ive tried changing the field name so to something else so its not that ive misspelt it. Any ideas?

```
addPinsToMap : function() {

        var carMapVar = window.router.carsCollection;

        var names = carMapVar.pluck("lat");
        console.log(names);

    }
```

Comment: Create a minimal test case, with maybe 5 or so models (yes, that's the right term) in the collection, and show the code to set things up along with the results. There's nothing obviously wrong with what you've shown, so the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: I believe the problem may be that im aiming at the collection instead on the models within the collection.

Comment: Make sure that the 'lat' attribute is in fact in the 'attributes' property of the model and not just a property of the model. You can check that simply with `_.each( carMapVar, function( car ) { console.log( car.attributes ) })`.

Comment: can you print out the console.log of the collection? And can you print out the console.log of an example model? This will help a lot ;)

Comment: Hi this question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17170708/how-to-log-a-certain-field-of-every-model-in-a-collection/17170849?noredirect=1#comment24868252_17170849

In much the same way as you suggest. It seems my data structures were different to what i thought they were.