# How to log a certain field of every model in a collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

Hi im trying to output every "lat" field from my collection. However anything i do returns the right number of results but they all say undefined, the data is definitely there and the names are definitely right. I've tried using pluck and _.each with a get inside the function and all it ever says is undefined.

This is the current method im trying

```
var ccLocal = window.router.carsCollection;
_.each(ccLocal.models, function(model) {
    console.log(model.lat);
})
```

logging `ccLocal` returns the entire collection with all its data so its definitely there. What am i doing wrong?

Using `model.get("lat")` also fails.

Using `console.log(ccLocal.at(0).attributes);` returns this

```
Object {unitID: "03_Cow_30", positionHistory: Array[1]}
positionHistory: Array[1]
0: Object
estimatedSpeed: "39"
isToday: false
lastSoundFileName: "F11"
lastSoundRange: "11"
lastSoundTime: "2008-10-29 20:38:25"
lat: "51.466227"
long: "-0.491647"
minutesAgo: 1016726
status: "1"
time: "2011-07-13 16:03:37"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
unitID: "03_Cow_30"
__proto__: Object
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you want to do `model.get('lat')`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Underscore collection pluck returning undefineds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168196/underscore-collection-pluck-returning-undefineds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, so your model `attributes` data structure is not what everyone thought. Based on your `attributes` structure, you need something like this. It's a bit fragile due to assuming positionHistory is an array with at least one element, but that's where your data is.

```
var ccLocal = window.router.carsCollection;
_.each(ccLocal.models, function(model) {
   console.log(model.get('positionHistory')[0].lat);
})
```

Comment: This just returns undefined over and over again, what would cause any method to return undefined even though the data is definitely in the collection?

Comment: Can you just log `ccLocal.at(0).attributes` so we can see what data your model has? It looks like probably your models don't have the data you think they have.

Comment: Sorry for the mess, i dont know any better way to show you. This is the first element that comes out of the collection, i drilled down a few levels to find the fields i want to show you.

Comment: What do you mean "drilled down a few levels"? Based on that log output and your snippets, what you have should be working provided you change to `model.get("lat")`. If you still can't make sense of it, you're off in the weeds and you need to post a complete working JSFiddle so we can see where else in your code you have a bug.

Comment: Well when the console output is created it shows up like the screenshot. So i had to "drill down" to find the attributes

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly though there is an extra ")" after lat. I did not make this data collection so with my limited knowledge of collections i assumed the data would be in the same format as example collections ive seen. Again thank you very much!